# binding in wpf/ C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a xml file which I want to edit using automatic data binding in my wpf application.
Can anyone lead me into this please? For example, can I add all the xml contents into a treeview? More...if I modify the xml by hand, will the treeview auto-refresh with the new values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [XmlDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx). Here is an article about how to use it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfXml2WayDataBinding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For a really good introduction to a very maintainable way to do databinding in WPF, see [Josh Smith's article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

It doesn't explicitly discuss binding to XML, but it should give you a really good idea of the power of WPF databinding.